# A-vs-An, some example usage please

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have just come across the potentially very useful "A-vs-An" Nuget package that works out whether to use "A" or "An" in front of a string.

However I am missing some example code to show how to use it in a C#/.NET environment.

["A-vs-Ans" Website](https://code.google.com/p/a-vs-an/)

I may be missing the obvious...???

Could someone point be to a sample please as I unable to work out how to use the DLL at present.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to do the following in order to use it (assuming you've referenced the DLL in your project):

```
var result = AvsAnLib.AvsAn.Query("object");
string article = result.Article;
```

You can find some documentation for the `Query` method at the bottom of the main `*.cs` file in the project: https://code.google.com/p/a-vs-an/source/browse/A-vs-An/A-vs-An-DotNet/AvsAn.cs